# Why All for One never stole One for All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

All for One is the most powerful superhuman with the exception of All Might who has the quirk One for All. If All for One has the quirk who makes him able to steal quirks, and All Might is the only person he can't defeat, why All for One doesnt steal One for All and let All Might quirkless to be able to defeat him?

Comment: Why do people write questions without referring to the title of the work they are talking about? The only Stack Exchange I've seen that's worse than this one for that is the video game one. Even I knew the work and I wasn't sure if it was actually the one the OP was talking about until the term "quirk" came up.

Comment: @DKNguyen because it's redundant if you already have it in the tag?

Comment: Was that always there? Because I could have sworn I went looking for a tag and didn't see one.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer this but if you paid attention to the Anime/Manga its mentioned several times.

All for one cannot be taken by force, it must be given willingly.

When Midoria was worried that Stain would get One for All after consuming his blood, All Might explained that it must be given willingly.

Comment: Have you seen the movie My Hero Academia: Heroes Rising? I dont want to spoil you but what we see there seems to show your answer is wrong.

Comment: Look this picture if you want to be spoiled https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LryNTBFSVW4/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @Pablo I have seen the movie. And you'll find that he (Nine) could not take One for All. He had a weaker version of ALL for One and its stated multiple times that All for one can not take One for All. https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/All_For_One_(Quirk),     https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Nine

Comment: but many theorizes he couldnt (even though he was able to pop it up) because One for All is actually 9 quirks, and he has slots for only 9 quirks so he couldnt add 9 quirks more. I think the wikia states One for All can't be stolen due to what All Might said, but All Might was talking about someone stealing a piece of hair for example and eating it to steal it that way. This makes senses considering Nine's reaction when he tried to incorporate One for All, it looked like he couldnt incorporate it to him, not that he wasnt able to steal it from Midoriya

Comment: @Pablo The move shows the previous OFA vestiges preventing the quirk being stolen. Its most likely that has happened before since AFO never stole it back from All Might or his predecessors. And the most likely reason for that is because he can't.

Comment: I'm watching now a subtitled image of Nine trying to steal One for All which says "No, I don't have enough free spaces to steal them all". The image of the 9 holders can symbolize that they are 9 quirks and not just one

Comment: @Pablo I wouldn't agree that subtitles are the best way to prove it since translation are often wildly out or straight up wrong. Also both All Might and Deku were born quirkless and Deku is the 9th user of OFA so there can only be max 7 quirks there.